# pgadmin 4 v5 startup issues

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

i just installed the new pgadmin 4 v5.0, after uninstalling v4.30.
so it uses its own desktop app window, instead of browser
(web interface is still available, but its not the default)

my questions:

- how to make it start in fullscreen nicely, and remember the setting? i tried changing its shortcut properties from Normal -> Maximized window, but that seems to cause some weird behavior: some dialog windows get stuck in upper left corner, also splash screen gets maximized too..
- it also hangs at startup every time for whole 80(!!) seconds, once the main window frame appears after splash screen. I didn't have such issue with v4.30. i only have two small databases for learning Postgres (v13.1)
- it also doesn't seem to remember the last opened database/table, other previously expanded subtrees in left pane, like v4.30 could

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to v5.2 and it had similar start up issues. I was just met with a blank screen.

A work around that works for me every time is to right click on the top window bar and click move, then everything shows up.